# Sorting by value and key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I was searching for something to sort a list of pairs by values and keys in Python. I have found this:

```
list.sort(key=lambda (k, v): (-v, k))
```

How does this lambda function work?

Comment: Well what *are* your doubts, and what have you done to clarify them? Have you tried testing it in an interpreter, for example?

Comment: You want to sort the dictionary on `key` or `value`?

Comment: I want to sort a list by value and then sort by key those which have the same value. What i didn't understand was the -v because i tried this without the - and seemed to me that the list is sorted only by values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction. `list` do not contain value in `key`, `value` pair. `key`: `value` pair are present in dictionary. Below is the code for dictionary sorting on values and then on keys:

```
>>> d = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 3, 'almond':2 , 'beetroot': 3, 'peach': 4}
>>> sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k))
[('peach', 4), ('banana', 3), ('beetroot', 3), ('almond', 2), ('apple', 2)]
```

Explanation:
`d.iteritems()` returns a [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) object. In `sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k))`, `key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k)` means sorting will be firstly based on the decreasing order of value i.e `-v` and then ascending order of key i.e `k`.

Same logic is applicable on the code for sorting the list as is mentioned in the question.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I think that OP wants an explanation - not a demo.

Comment: Updated answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It is sorting a list by a pair of values. Since it's sorting a list there aren't any key, value pairs, but more two values next to each other. 
The way it's written it sorts by the second value in reverse, **then** sorts by the first value in normal ascending order.

Here it is demonstrated:

```
l1 = [[2,2],[3,1],[1,2],[4,1]]

l1.sort(key=lambda(k,v):(-v,k))

l1
=> [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

updated for python 3

```
>>> d = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 3, 'almond':2 , 'beetroot': 3, 'peach': 4}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))
[('peach', 4), ('banana', 3), ('beetroot', 3), ('almond', 2), ('apple', 2)]
```